# What is the hangeul for the personal name 金知桓?

Tags: hanja, names

What is the hangeul for the personal name 金知桓?

I understand that the family name is 김 but what is the given name?

I have searched all the dictionaries I have and google doesn't give me anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 金知桓 김지환

1) 知 : 알 지 => know

example : 지성 = intelligence

2) 桓 : 씩씩할 환 => brave

Comment: Thanks, but what would the name be? 김알지환? Is it ok with four syllables in a name?

Comment: 지환 is a name (Here 알 is a meaning).

Comment: Ok, is the name 김지환 then? Could you perhaps edit the answer to make that clear?

Answer (score 4):

An online method of finding 한글 for 한자:

https://hanja.dict.naver.com/

[image]

Either draw the Chinese charater on the box given at the right, or copy and paste the character in the text box on the left, and it suggests a list of words using this 한자 as well as it's 한글 equivalent