# How do you convert chinese name to korean name

Tags: spoken-korean, names

I would like to convert my chinese name into korean name ，how do i do it? My chinese name is 梁博勋

Comment: Also see here: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/4904/what-is-the-hangeul-for-the-personal-name-%e9%87%91%e7%9f%a5%e6%a1%93/4906#4906

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Hanja dictionary in Korean (https://dic.daum.net)

The letters in your name are as the following in Korean.

梁 들보 량

博 넓을 박

勛 공 훈

"Letter Meaning Pornunciation" is the way to understand the above lines. (This is the typical way for Koreans when learning Hanja.)
As you may know, Koreans use traditional Chinese letters, so your last letter is different, but I guess you may know about these letters better than I do.

So, you name should pronounce **"량박훈" or "양박훈"**.

Either way is fine. It's up to your choice as to how to read your first letter.

For your info, your letters would reveal to native Koreans that you are probably not Korean even though the name is written in Korean with typical three-letter length because the pronunciation combination of your first name (박훈) is not the usual one in Korea. Also, if you choose 량 instead of 양, many natives would assume that you are from either China or North Korea.

Answer (score 0):

Since Korean of course has Hanja as an integrated part of the language you could simply just apply Hanja reading to the characters in your name. It seems that you're a Mainland Chinese with the use of 簡體字 whereas Korean of course uses 正體字 and its own 異體字 so your name would be 梁博勳 rather than 梁博勋 and would be pronounced 梁博勳(양/량박훈) the two forms of 양/량 differ in pronunciation whether you're in the South(양) or the North(량). In your case 박훈 is actually a name that exists ([https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/朴勳](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%B4%E5%8B%B3)) albeit 朴(박) is a family name in this case.