# How can I translate my Chinese name to a Korean name?

Tags: translation, hangul

My name is 高安音 but I can't seem to find an appropriate translation into Korean.

Comment: look here for relevant information: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/4904/what-is-the-hangeul-for-the-personal-name-%e9%87%91%e7%9f%a5%e6%a1%93/4906#4906

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "translate" exactly, but the name can be clearly pronounced in Korean as 고안음, as all three characters are in common use.

I think using this simple Korean reading as your name is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a Korean name which sounds similar to your original pronunciation, your family name 高 will be **고**(go).

*[Mandarin]*
Next, 安音(ānyīn) is very similar to **안인**(an-in), but I can tell you if you want more common names.

- **안희**(neutral): an-hui -> This will actually sound like 'anhi' or 'ani'
- **아인**(female): a-in -> This is used a lot, but I don't recommend this one. '고아인' can mean to be an orphan in Korean.
- **안일**(male): an-il -> This is not very common, but also good.

*[Cantonese]*
安音(ngon1 jam1) is a bit harder, because it sounds like **응온 얌**(eung-on-yam).

- **연아**(female): yeon-ah -> Sorry.. Cantonese name is very hard to change, so I think this is the most similar one.